# Why does my Java program create an infinite # of windows? (Uses threads and NO WHILE LOOPS)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, jframe

**Question:** So I am attempting to understand how threads work with graphics so I created a program that should set the color of the screen to red using a user thread. However, when I run the program, **it opens my JFrame window an infinite number of times on top of each other and I have to quit the program for it to stop**. How do I prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE:*** So a lot of you have explained to me the culprit (commented out now): frame.add(new MWT) that repeatedly calls the constructor and creates a new object. However, **How do I simply add the Canvas to the JFrame without any static instances? Thanks**

**Class Code**

```
    public class MWT  extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private Thread fast;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        MWT draw = new MWT();

    }
    public MWT(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Thread Drawings");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setSize(600,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // CULPRIT
        //frame.add(new MWT());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start();
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (fast== null){
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.exit(0); 
        }

    }

    private void start() {
        if (fast != null){
            return;
            }
        else{
            fast = new Thread(this);
            fast.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        render(g2d);
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0,600,500);
        stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Satanic move of some sort? I am new to this and did not realize that. @Makoto

Comment: Maybe I was misreading.  You did say infinite windows...but this does somewhat seem to be the convention.  Let me read the code a bit closer.

Comment: Because you have an infinite recursion. `while` loops aren't the only way to loop indefinitely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the constructor for `MWT` at the line `add(new MWT())`. So when you construct a new `MWT`, you create a new `JFrame`, then you called `MWT()` again, creating a new `JFrame`, calling `MWT()` again, and so on. Eventually you should run into a stack overflow though.

To solve that, you could either extend `JFrame`, and add components that go inside it in its constructor, or just add the current instance.

```
public class MWT extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    // change the constructor so it doesn't make a new JFrame
    // change the constructor so it doesn't add a new instance to the JFrame
    // leave the rest unchanged
}

public class ThreadedGraphicsDemo extends JFrame {
    private MWT mwt;

    public ThreadedGraphicsDemo(MWT mwt) {
        this.mwt = mwt;

        add(mwt);
        // set exit behavior, size, pack, visible etc
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MWT mwt = new MWT();
        ThreadedGraphicsDemo tgd = new tgd(mwt);
    }
}
```

This approach will allow you to easily change the GUI, and behavior in the future.

The quick fix:
instead of `add(new MWT())`, change it to `add(this)` to add the instance of `MWT` that you've instantiated

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How would I add a non static instance of MWT (static instances in this case are a big no no right?) to the frame then? @Alex Yan

Comment: I think you should extend `JFrame`, and in its constructor, add the GUI that goes inside it, because if you think about it, `MWT` is a canvas that goes into a frame of some type, so it would make more sense for a frame to add components that it's containing, as opposed to having a canvas add a new instance of itself into a container it created

Comment: I use Canvas because I prefer using a BufferStrategy. Is this available in JPanel or JFrame as well? @AlexYan

Comment: It shouldn't matter I don't think, as the default `add()` for `JFrame` will add the component to its `contentPane`, which is a `JPanel`, so you'll still be using the `Thread`, and `Canvas` stuff you added with `MWT`

Comment: Wait, I am sorry. I am not sure what you are trying to say for some reason. How do I use my Canvas BufferStrategy if I am not extending Canvas? @Alex Yan

Comment: Sorry, 4AM doesn't really help lol. I mean if you extended JFrame or JPanel, you will still keep your MWT, but instead of creating a container, and adding itself into the container within the constructor of MWT, the extended versions of JFrame/JPanel will add an instance of MWT into it. And because MWT is using BufferStrategy to draw, that functionality will be retained

Comment: It's kind of like a group working on a project. The leader asks the artist to draw something. How do they draw it? It's completely up to the artist, not the leader. Usually. In that case, the leader would be the JFrame that you plan on extending, and the artist would be the Canvas. When the JFrame paints, it will ask each of the compoenents it's containing to draw themselves. And your Canvas will draw itself with BufferStrategy because that's how you defined it

Comment: Haha well that is always a source of errors lol. Ok, so are you saying maybe like **MWT extends JFrame(Or JPanel) implements Runnable** And then frame.add(this) in the contractor along with drawing with a BufferStrategy? @AlexYan

Comment: Thanks! I added more to the answer. It's getting late, I'll be going to sleep

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tracked down the source of your infinitely spawning windows.  You're instantiating the object you're constructing in constructor.

```
frame.add(new MWT());
```

The thing with this is that, since the object isn't completely done constructing your instance, it's going to still go off and create an instance of that, which leads to a lot of calls to the `MWT` object.

If you want to add the *current* instance of the `MWT` object you're constructing, you can use `this` instead:

```
frame.add(this);
```

Comment: Ok, that works in the sense that no more infinite windows, however, now i get an ""IllegalArgumentException" Width and Height cannot be <=0;" Also, why does the use of this keep the current object from calling on its own constructor and hence the loop? Thanks @Makoto

Comment: I'm not much of a Java GUI guy, so I wouldn't be able to fill in the esoterics.  I would encourage you to look into a debugger and be sure that you're passing around what it is you need to be.